# FireBase Authentication mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm trying to add an Authentication and Sign in service to my app, I'm following all of the steps told on FireBase although I can't get through this part, it says that the error is

> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Java.lang.String, Java.lang.String) in
>   FireBaseAuth cannot be applied to (Android.widget.text,
>   Android.widget.text)

Thanks in advance for any help given. The code is the following:

```
public void Register(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BottomActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    attemptLogin();

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener( this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d( TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success" );
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI( user );
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failed");
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI( null );
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

email/password:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView email;
private EditText password;
```

Comment: show how you initialized variables email and password

Comment: Also remove that extra space `(email, password)`

Comment: Please show us what are the values for `emai` and `password` when trying to authenticate. Please also reponde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo     private AutoCompleteTextView email;
    private EditText password;

Comment: Have you tried ribbit's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener( this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d( TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success" );
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI( user );
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failed");
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI( null );
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked, now, how to I go from this, to, every time that a user presses the "register" button, it creates a new user on Firebase?

Comment: Great to hear that

Answer (score 0):

From reading the error you're getting, it's saying that the type of the parameters you're passing are not matching what the method expects. It expects `String` objects. So you'd need to extract that value from your `TextView` and `EditText`.

Try passing `email.getText().toString()` and `password.getText().toString` as parameters instead of `email` and `password`.

So

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple you should add a classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' in dependencies of built.gradle
and then add id 'com.google.gms.google-services' in built.gradle(app)
that's all.

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for your input. However, I managed to solve this about 2 years ago hahaah.